# Find and count two table with difference column change order

Tags: sql-server

I have two table below:

Table A:

```
N1 N2 N3
6  11 20
```

Table B:

```
N1 N2 N3 N4 N5 N6 N7 N8
1  2  5  6  10 12 14 15
1  9  10 15 16 18 19 20
4  5  8  9  10 14 15 16
```

I want to count data duplication in table B with table A and result:

1

1

0

```
my code (only working for tableb have 1 row):
declare @dem tinyint,
        @t1 tinyint,
        @t2 tinyint,
        @t3 tinyint,
set @dem = 0    
select @t1 = (select [n1] from [tablea])
select @t2 = (select [n2] from [tablea])
select @t3 = (select [n3] from [tablea])
if exists(select 1 from [tableb] where [n1] = @t1 or [n2] = @t1 or [n3] = @t1 or [n4] = @t1 or [n5] = @t1 or [n6] = @t1 or [n7] = @t1 or [n8] = @t1)
begin
    set @dem = @dem + 1
end
if exists(select 1 from [tableb] where [n1] = @t2 or [n2] = @t2 or [n3] = @t2 or [n4] = @t2 or [n5] = @t2 or [n6] = @t2 or [n7] = @t2 or [n8] = @t2)
begin
    set @dem = @dem + 1
end
if exists(select 1 from [tableb] where [n1] = @t3 or [n2] = @t3 or [n3] = @t3 or [n4] = @t3 or [n5] = @t3 or [n6] = @t3 or [n7] = @t3 or [n8] = @t3)
begin
    set @dem = @dem + 1
end
---
select @dem
```

Please support me SQL code.
Thanks.

Comment: Please don't provide links of images to data. Data is text, and should be posted as formatted `text` or as DDL and DML statements. What have you tried to solve the problem? Stack Overflow isn't a free support/coding website, so please don't treat it as one. It's a Q&A website for programmi g problems you have tried (and failed) to resolve yourself. Please update you question with a question, along with addressing the other comments and a volunteer here will be happy to help you. Thanks.

Comment: What's 1 1 0? and how do you check for duplication?

Comment: The first row in table B duplicate data with table A: 1 record. The second row in table B duplicate data with table A: 1 record. The three row in table B duplicate data with table A: 0 record

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cross join the tables and use the IN operator.

```
select
  case when a.n1 in (
    b.n1, b.n2, b.n3, b.n4, b.n5, b.n6, b.n7, b.n8
  ) then 1 else 0 end +
  case when a.n2 in (
    b.n1, b.n2, b.n3, b.n4, b.n5, b.n6, b.n7, b.n8
  ) then 1 else 0 end +
  case when a.n3 in (
    b.n1, b.n2, b.n3, b.n4, b.n5, b.n6, b.n7, b.n8
  ) then 1 else 0 end counter
from tablea a cross join tableb b
```

See the [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=sqlserver_2017&fiddle=fd0adb3b6af4b36b457dd7b95fc269b3).
Results:

```
> | counter |
> | ------: |
> |       1 |
> |       1 |
> |       0 |
```

Comment: I used Sql Server 2008 R2 and copy code from Demo. It's not working. Does this code working on Sql Server 2008 R2? The error message: 'concat' is not a recognized built-in function name. and Incorrect syntax near 'counter'.